# Always start Nautilus with specified window size

Tags: nautilus

Is there a way to make nautilus start with specified window size (like the terminal)?

Currently, whenever I stretch the window or maximise it, it will then keep opening with the size that was last used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CompizConfig-SettingsManager to do that.

1. First install it

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open it
3. Enable **Window Rules** plugin.
4. While, you're in that plugin, go to **Size rules** tab. Click **New** button to add a new rule. In that rule, specify the size and on the *Sized Window* field write

   ```
   class=Nautilus
   ```

   Save the rule.

Now, nautilus will be started with the size you specified in the rule

Comment: Great, exactly what I wanted. Although the program is somewhat buggy, I set it to 60x60 just to test it and now it's stuck at 60x60 even if I change the values. I'll try again after restart.

Comment: well, 60x60 is too small! I tested using 800x600

Comment: Oh, I see what the problem was, I kept changing from 60x60 to 200x200 and 300x300 and nothing was happening. But nautilus has a minimum window size so anything below that will not change the size. I set it to 1000x600 now.

Comment: Although there seems to be a bug when the window is maximized, because it automatically resizes the window to the preset value when I change focus.